# JS DOM: How to access nested element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

It's very tricky question, but please can someone help me with it?

Let's suppose we have code, similar to that:

```
<div id='main'>

<div class='class1'>
<div class='class2'>
<div class='class3'>
<div class='class4'>
<div class='class5'>
<div class='class6'>
<div class='class7'>
<div class='class8'>

<button class='button'/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to access **button** inside these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector()` to select elements just like you would with CSS, in your case:

```
document.querySelector("#main button")
```